# Azure SQL Databases and Managed Instances in CMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

Has anybody come up with a good way of having MIs or Azure SQL Databases registered in Central Management Server?

Only option is SQL Auth (Which you cant save the password for) or Windows Auth which doesnt work with AAD

Comment: ARe you asking how to use an Azure SQL Database or a Managed Instance *as* the CMS? If so, it's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-ver16#create-a-central-management-server) that (at current) that host must use Windows Authentication.